# Increment the counter of each category using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am using php for my application and i have 180 vendors registered on my app,each vendor has a unique id which is stored in database.I have to implement a counter that each time a user clicks on a view details button of a particular vendor the counter of that particular vendor is incremented and is shown on the vendor portal of that vendor . I don't have an exact idea how to approach this problem so I can show that how many times the user has clicked the view details button of that particular vendor.Can anyone guide me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using `php` there is no hard and fast rule to update counter on database. You should create a method that `update` counter on your database and use `ajax` to call that `function` using `javascript` or when user clicks on view detail then I think the page loads from new `url`. If this is the case then before rendering the page you should include call a function to increment the counter associated with the vendor in your `database`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a table in the DB with vendor id and a counter. Each time a user clicks on a view details button of a particular vendor increment the counter, i.e update the counter in the DB using ajax call. Hope you are familiar to call a ajax function and update the DB.